# Qual meio de Remover recursivamente caracteres acentuados, de nomes de arquivos

Tags: script, bash, shell, caracteres, unicode

Tentei outros scripts que encontrei pela internet(*os que encontrei), mas sem sucesso. Então quero saber de algum(ns) de vocês como fazer essa tarefa automatizada/recursiva.

Shell Script Retirado de: https://tsgii.blogspot.com/

```
set meta-flag on


set output-meta on


set convert-meta off

#!/bin/bash

NOMBRES_FICHEROS=$(ls)

for i in $NOMBRES_FICHEROS
do
        echo '...TRATANDO EL FICHERO: '$i'...'
        cat $i | tr [:upper:] [:lower:] > def_$i
        cat $i | tr "ÁÉÍÓÚÑ" "AEIOUN" > def_$i
        mv def_$i $i
done
```

Sem comentários, não funcionou! Talvez eu não tenha o Sr. Bash como interpretador de comandos CLI

Shell Script Retirado de: http://www.alexandrepinheiro.com/2011/05/shell-script-para-retirar-os-acentos.html

```
#!/bin/bash


for file in *;
do
newname=`echo "$file" | iconv -t 'ascii//TRANSLIT'`


mv "$file" "$newname"


done
```

Este outro que encontrei também não rodou em meu sistema, acho que não possou mesmo o interpretador Bash, apenas Ash linkado para Bash.

Shell Script Retirado de: https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/topico/Shell-Script/Remover-caracteres-esquisitos/

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in *
do
    # ^  Quando esse chapeuzinho aparece no início de uma lista de caracteres significa negação;
    j=`echo "$i" | sed 's/[^A-Za-z0-9_.]//g'`
    # Vai remover todos os acentos das letras indicadas - https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/topico/Shell-Script/Script-para-retirar-acentos
    j=`echo "$j" | sed 'y/áÁàÀãÃâÂéÉêÊíÍóÓõÕôÔúÚçÇ/aAaAaAaAeEeEiIoOoOoOuUcC/'`
    mv "$i" "$j"
    echo "Acento(s) removido de: $i"
done
```

Esse ja funcionu em partes, digo isto, pois a alteração faz troca um tanto esquisita, troca até caracteres sem acento também [onde não tem].

Esses foram os quais encontrei.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você poderá utilizar o comando `iconv`. Esta função irá converter os caracteres de uma codificação para outra. O comando é simples.

**Conteúdo de um arquivo:**

```
iconv -f UTF8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT < input.txt > output.txt
```

**Conteúdo de uma variável:**

```
$psr_new_value = $(echo $psr_variable | iconv -f UTF8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT)
```

---

**Explicação do Comando:**

```
 iconv  -f UTF8  -t ASCII//TRANSLIT < input.txt > output.txt
└──┬──┘└───┬───┘└───┬───┘  └───┬───┘
   │       │        │          │
   │       │        │          └──── Ele pode ser aproximado por meio de um ou vários caracteres semelhantes.Information Interchange
   │       │        └─────────────── Codificação de destino
   │       └──────────────────────── Codificação de entrada
   └──────────────────────────────── Comando
```

---

**Exemplo Completo:**

Segue abaixo a estrutura e código utilizado no teste.

**Estrutura de arquivos antes:**

```
.
├── andré.txt
├── cajá.php
├── joão.txt
├── ñãõ.txt
└── vou_à_praia.txt

0 directories, 5 files
```

**Código:**

```
#/bin/sh

for file in *.txt;
do
    mv $file $(echo $file | iconv -f UTF8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT)
done
```

**Estrutura de arquivos após:**

```
.
├── andre.txt
├── cajá.php
├── joao.txt
├── nao.txt
└── vou_a_praia.txt

0 directories, 5 files
```

Comment: Para identificar a sua *shell*, utilize `echo $SHELL`

Comment: Como escrevi antes da edição, favor verificar. Qualquer coisa posso remover a resposta e editá-la posteriormente.

Comment: @DiegoHenrique Adicionei um exemplo com o `/bin/sh`

Comment: Testei mas ao rodar o comando which iconv descobri que não possuo e não encontrei no repositorio do sistema Slitaz 5. Uma pena, ja que poderia dar certo. Mas ta valendo!

Comment: ValdeirPsr pode sugerir ao @DiegoHenrique compilar ele mesmo o libiconv, primeiro baixe em https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/libiconv/ --- extraia o .tar.gz escolhido, então navegue até a pasta com o conteudo extraido e execute: `./configure --prefix=/usr/local`, `make` e `make install` . PS: não testei

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Vi sua sugestão, mas seria interessante algo retro-compatibilidade [algo que ja tenha em praticamente todo sistema operativo] `/bin/sh`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Tal como tentei -> `$ ls -w1 *.txt | while read line; do mv "$line" "$(echo $line | tr 'ÁÉÍÓÚÑ' 'AEIOUN')"; done`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Para renomear diversos arquivos você pode usar um `loop`,  pra entrar nas subpastas você teria que trocar o comando `ls` pelo `find`. O comando `rename` usa a mesma sintaxe _regex_ do `sed`, mas dá pra se virar bem sem ele se precisar...  Ja o comando `mv` não funciona de jeito nenhum por causa dos espaços nos nomes, da erros. Então se faz necessário remover os espaços -> `$ for i in *.txt; do mv "$i" "`echo $i | tr ' ' '_'`"; done`

Comment: @Diego e Valdeir, lhes garanto uma coisa, iconv (ou libs equivalentes) não existem por acaso, querer fazer na mão não `ÁÉÍÓÚÑ => AEIOUN` pode funcionar se tiver certeza do CODEC, entenda que o `Á` do utf-8 não é a mesma coisa do `Á` do latin1 (window-1252, iso-8859-1 e equivalentes/aproximados), o iconv detecta a codificação, pode até tentar criar algo na mão, mas vai ser bem mais complexo que uma linha só, provavelmente vai ter que enumerar todas variações de codecs possiveis, criar algo para remover definitivamente se o codec não for suportado [...]

Comment: [...] , quando chega a um nivel de complexidade assim talvez o melhor seja usar o que já existe, embarcar um software para isto, criar algo em [tag:c] ou [tag:c++] proprio e assim resolver de vez com algo garantido para evitar problemas de codecs.

Comment: Concordo com o @GuilhermeNascimento. Baixei o sistema operacional (SO) e vi que ele é bastante simples (menos de 50MB a versão live-cd). Em alguns testes com `sed`, `awk`, `tr` etc. Você até tem um resultado simples, porém não é o esperado. Caso você queira algo mais simples, pode instalar o `perl` e fazer um *script* básico. Caso você pretenda instalar esse *SO* em diversos dispositivos, você pode manter uma versão com `docker`.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Grato pela sua bela explicação, também concordo com o que você diz. Pois também notei isto,  a "codificação" variada. Por hora estou utilizando `iconv` na distro CDLinux-0.9.7.1 a mesma traz esta ferramenta consigo, além de ser uma distro Live-CD e USB, podendo ser instalado lado-a-lado de SO Windows. No meu caso dei um jeitnho de instalar  manualmente no HD. Por agora, esta me servindo muito bem, álias ja uso ela ha muito tempo. A partir dela, vou utilizando `iconv` nela e pensarei mais tarde em elaborar um shell script universal, pra dar conta tarefa onde não há `iconv`